# Can Google Action request Google Assistant to handle a request?

Tags: actions-on-google

I would like to write a Google Action that will automate a sequence of requests to Google Assistant. For example, if I ask the assistant to talk with my app, the result would be starting a timer for 5 minutes and playing a song from Google Play Music on a defined group of speakers.
I was looking for a way that my fulfillment is able to ask back the assistant to handle a request as if it was received from the user. Is it possible? How?

Comment: The short answer is no, you cannot send a command back to the Google Assistant from a third-party action.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the speaker to a raspi or some other pc and send back to it an mp3 file that says "ok, google play music". But it is a hacky workaround I guess.
Maybe with another device or a smarthome skill you can use to open this channel. If you build the messages by yourself.

On the other hand maybe Push notifications can handle it in future. But i am not sure with the documentation.  https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates